# if typeA in [typeB.typeA for typeB in typeBlist]: ... accessing typeB within the if clause?

Tags: python, list, attributes

The full example code:

```
for typeA in typeAlist:
  if typeA in [typeB.typeA for typeB in typeBlist]:
    return typeB
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but it feels like there would be a neat way to retrieve the typeB object that matched the typeA object.

The only way I can think of making it work is to have a nested for loop, iterating over typeBlist until the typeA attribute matches, then breaking.  Is there a cleaner way?  Or is that actually sufficiently clean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `if` within your list comprehension:

```
[typeB for typeB in typeBlist if typeB.typeA == typeA]
```

This would return all the members of `typeBlist` for which `typeB.typeA == typeA`.

If you're sure there's only a single match you can use a generator expression to stop working through the whole list:

```
try:
    return (typeB for typeB in typeBlist if typeB.typeA == typeA).next()
except StopIteration:
    return None
```

If you're doing this lookup a lot it might be easier to create a `dict` to map from `typeA` to `typeB`.

```
lookup = dict((typeB.typeA,typeB) for typeB in typeBlist)
```

You can then re-use this like so:

```
typeB = lookup[typeA]
```

If you might have many `typeB` entries for each `typeA` your lookup would map `typeA` to a `list` of `typeB`s:

```
from collections import defaultdict
lookup = defaultdict(list)
for typeB in typeBlist:
    lookup[typeB.typeA].append(typeB)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
matching_typeBs = [ x for x in typeBlist if x.typeA in typeAlist ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or the very same with filter statement(note that it is on your own to choose whether to use filter or list comprehension but second one is usually faster):

```
filter(lambda x: x.typeA in typeAlist, typeBlist)
```